# Angular ContentChildren(Component) get any type

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I know you can get the children by specifying a specific component type `@ContentChildren(SpecificComponent)` but can I use `@ContentChildren(SOMETHING)` and get a component regardless of its type, like a generic component?

Comment: if you use ContentChildren you received a QueryList<any> (yes is a QueryList, not any). Well in the example https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#basic-example you receive a QueryList<ChildDirective>, but you can use "any"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why someone downvoted this without saying why but ended up finding the solution:

```
@ContentChildren('childComponent') childComponents;
```

I pass a string into the contentchildren instead of a component. The string allows me to use a reference a selector (#childComponent)

Comment: Puts the responsibility on the consumer to know and always include a specific template reference instead of being able to include anything and have it picked up by `ContentChildren()`. And it's a hacky solution to include the same template reference to multiple elements.

Comment: @KevinBeal do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: But #childComponent is only for one item. So in this situation you'd want to use @ContentChild instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Component({
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    constructor(private readonly elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
        // do wathever you want with element.children
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always create a directive if I need to do this for a list of children:

```
@Directive({ 
    selector: '[childComponent]',
    standalone: true
})
export class GenericChildDirective { }
```

Then in the component:

```
@ContentChildren(GenericChildDirective) children!: QueryList<GenericChildDirective>;
```

I actually don't think there's a way to do this as originally asked.

Note: This is basically the same as the Angular example https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#tab-pane-example

Comment: There are some possible selector options explained in the docs in a fairly cryptic way. eg. "Any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component (e.g. @ContentChildren(SomeService) someService: SomeService)". Now I'm not exactly sure what this means, but perhaps it's possible to capture something common to all components such as the new DestroyRef. But even if it's possible it sounds too confusing and hacky for me to even attempt it.